# Bitly URL Shortner Code example for beginner

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a bitly shortener in vb.net

What I did:

-created the account in bitly

-created the token

I searched for code and want to use those snippets:

```
    'String for token
    Dim tokenString As String = "xxxxxxxxxmytokenxxxxxxxx"
    'Stream for the responce
    Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream
    'Stream reader to read the stream to a string
    Dim stringStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    'String to be read to
    Dim responseString As String
    'The webrequest that is querying
    Dim webRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten")
    'The collection of headers
    Dim webHeaderCollection As WebHeaderCollection = webRequest.Headers
    'Adding a header
    webHeaderCollection.Add("xxxMyUsernamexxx:Bearer " + tokenString)
    'The web responce
    Dim webResponce As HttpWebResponse = CType(webRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    'Reading the web responce to a stream
    responseStream = webResponce.GetResponseStream()
    'Initializing the stream reader with our stream
    stringStreamReader = New StreamReader(responseStream)
    'Reading the stream to our string
    responseString = stringStreamReader.ReadToEnd.ToString
    'Ending the web responce
    webResponce.Close()
```

But I get this error:

[image: Image Error]

Has someone a code snippet for me which works already?

Comment: By default the WebRequest does an HTTP GET operation. You need to do a POST operation.

Answer (score 0):

A [405 HTTP Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) is also referred to as Method Not Allowed. Generally this happens when you send the incorrect method type. So for example, the endpoint is setup to accept GET requests but you've sent a POST request.

By default, the WebRequest will submit a GET but it looks like the API is expecting a POST. You can specify the method manually by using:

```vb
webRequest.request.Method = "POST"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one those answers where I entered a lot of code directly into the reply window, so while the general theme here is correct there WILL still be some bugs you need to work through:

```vb
Const tokenString As String = "xxxxxxxxxmytokenxxxxxxxx"
Const myUserName As String = "xxxMyUsernamexxx"
Const myGroupID As  String = "xxxxxxxxxxx" 

Public Shared Function ShortenUrl(urlToShorten As String) As String
    Using rq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten")
        Dim data As String = $"{{""group_guid"": ""{myGroupID}"", ""long_url"": ""{urlToShorten}""}}"

        rq.Headers.Add($"{myUserName}:Bearer {tokenString}")
        rq.Method = "POST"
        rq.ContentType = "application/json"
        rq.ContentLength = data.Length

        Using requestStream As Stream = rq.GetRequestStream()
            Dim postBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);
            rq.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
        End Using
    
        Using rsp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(rq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse), _
              str As Stream = rsp.GetResponseStream()), _
              rdr As New StreamReader(str)
                  Dim json As String = rdr.ReadToEnd()
                  ' Note: while the full json language is not "regular", and therefore not a good regex fit, the specific result we're looking for within the json **IS** regular
                  Return  Regex.Match(json, """link"": ?""(?<link>[^,;]+)""").Groups("link").Value
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```